# Firebase account linking prompt

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I understand how to link two Firebase accounts manually, by allowing a logged in user to select to link another account, and then using the `linkWithCredential' method.

However, is there a way to use Firebase's  `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException` to trigger a prompt to the user to link the auth method that they are trying to loggin in with, with that of the existing account?

After the research that I've done, I'm assuming not. However, any suggestions relating to this or similar approaches would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check this post on how to recover from `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322998/how-to-handle-firebaseauthusercollisionexception/46360107#46360107

Comment: At a glance that looks like a good solution. I look forward to testing its implementation. Thanks

Comment: Cool, glad this was helpful.